# Ran out of trampolines of type 2

Tags: ios, mono, unity-game-engine, aot

We develop our game with Unity 3D for iOS. Recently I merged my branch of code with another branch and run it with Unity editor. It works well. But when I ran app on iPad it crashes with message "Ran out of trampolines of type 2 in '/private/var/mobile/Applications//.app/Data/Managed/mscorlib.dll' (128)". I found out that  exception like this occured when interfaces are used heavily ([Ran out of trampolines of type 2](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/troubleshooting#Ran_out_of_trampolines_of_type_2)). Indeed, our project contains too many interfaces and each interface has many methods. Solution was being found as well - increase number of trampolines by typing option like -aot "nimt-trampolines=512". Could anybody explain me how number '512' depends from number of interfaces (maybe number of methods, etc)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to calculate the number, they depend on which interfaces you actually use in your app.

Here is a more detailed explanation: http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/Understanding-the-impact-of-trampolines-td4495086.html

Comment: @ghost3D: I believe it might happen with non-generic interfaces on generic types too.

Comment: Do you mean that if I heavily use List<ISomeInterface> or Dictionary<int, ISomeInterface> (ISomeInterface is anyone from large set of interfaces) I'll get ran out of trampolines type 2? or this might be happened when I implement non-generic interface, but type is generic (like public class SomeType<T> : ISomeInterface { ... } ?

Comment: The second case, SomeType<T> : ISomeInterface.